# Changing legend in geom_density

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I cannot understand why the legend is not changing given the following code. The same options do the trick with geom_histogram. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, color = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_density(aes(group = am)) +
  theme_classic() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
  labs(x = "Displacement", y = "Density") +
  scale_fill_manual(name="",values=c("black","gray"),labels=c("Foreign","Domestic"))
```

Comment: As you are mapping on the `color` aesthetic try with `guides(color = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))` and of course with `scale_color_manual`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `color` in your call of `aes()`. To modify the scale for this variable you need to use `scale_color_manual` and not `scale_fill_manual`.

It's tricky because `geom_histogram` does use `fill`, but `geom_density` uses `color`.

Working solution :

```
data(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, color = as.factor(am))) +
  geom_density(aes(group = am)) +
  theme_classic() +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
  labs(x = "Displacement", y = "Density") +
  scale_color_manual(name="",values=c("black","gray"),labels=c("Foreign","Domestic"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I should have caught that.